# breaking an array into subsets

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, subset

I am trying to get this function to split an array into subsets. each subset is to have numbers that are equal to the previous or within 1 from the previous number.
The example I have below should return two subsets but it returns {0, 1, 2, 3} instead. Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Also, is there a better way to dynamically create an array for each new subset? Thanks

```
function max_tickets() {
    var arr = [4, 13, 2, 3];
    var myarr = arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});


for(var i = 0; i<myarr.length; i++){

    var iplus = i+1;
    if(i === i || i === iplus){
       newArr= [];
       newArr.push(i);
    }else if (i !== i || i !== iplus){
       arr2 =[];
       arr2.push(i);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output from your example of `[4, 13, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
function max_tickets() {
    var arr = [4, 13, 2, 3];
    var myarr = arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    arrSubsets = [];
    arr1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
        if (myarr[i - 1] === undefined) {
            arr1.push(myarr[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (myarr[i] - myarr[i - 1] <= 1) {
            arr1.push(myarr[i]);
        }
        else {
            arrSubsets.push(arr1);
            arr1 = [];
            arr1.push(myarr[i]);
        }
    }
    if (arr1.length > 0)
        arrSubsets.push(arr1);                    
}
max_tickets();
```

Comment: Thank you, I added a couple of lines to it and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is usually called "partitioning". The generic version of the problem is to partition an array into sub-arrays using some "rule", or predicate, or condition, which specifies which partition a particular element is supposed to go into, or specifies that it should go into a new partition.

The pseudo code for doing this would be:

```
To partition an array:
  Initialize the resulting array
  For each element in the array
    If that element starts a new chunk
      Create a new empty chunk in the resulting array
   Add the element to the most recent chunk
   Return the result
```

This can be expressed in JS quite straightforwardly as

```
function partition(array, fn) {
  return array.reduce((result, elt, i, a) => {
    if (!i || !fn(elt, i, a)) result.push([]);
    result[result.length - 1].push(elt);
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

Now we need to write the function saying when a new partition should start:

```
// Is the element within one of the previous element?
function close(e, i, a) {
  return Math.abs(e - a[i-1]) > 1;
}
```

We can now partition the array with

```
partition([[4, 13, 2, 3], close)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your questions:

- Any idea on what I am doing wrong?.

Inside of your loop you are using `i` as if it is the value of the array, but the loop goes from `0` to the value of `myarr.length` in your particular case `4`, so that makes the value of `i` to be `0, 1, 2, 3`.

As you can see you are using the values of the `index` to compare, instead of using the values of the array in order to use the values of the array you must specify the `arrayname[index]`, in your case `myarr[i]` that will give you the values: `4, 13, 2, 3`.

- Also, is there a better way to dynamically create an array for each new subset?

Yes you can create an array inside of another array dynamically inside of a loop:

```
var b = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  b.push(['I am' + i, i]);
}
```

As you can see in the previous example I'm creating an array inside of the `b` array so once the loop finishes the `b` array will have 10 `arrays` inside of it with 2 elements each.

Comment: that can throw things off a bit lol.... thank you very much for pointing that out. cool profile pic btw